# HTML/Javascript: How to track if upload was aborted?

Tags: javascript, dom, upload, listeners, abort

**So for example we have an HTML file with a similar content to this:**

```
<body>
    <form action="/upload" type="post" id="upload-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file-input" />
    </form>
</body>
```

**What I want in javascript**

- To get notified when the server encounters an error and aborts the upload request
- To get notified when the user aborts the upload manually
- Or any kind of abort stuff which might occure

**Something Like:**

```
var form = document.getElementById('upload-form');
form.onabort = function(error){ 
     alert(error); 
}
```

Are there any native api or custom techniques for this in **javascript**?

Answer (score 0):

You could AJAX notify before the file upload begins and then store the number in either a session at the server or if you really want to a column in a database.

There is an onabort event handler however my understanding is that it's for img elements only. You could try and see if it would work for the various rendering engines though (Gecko: Firefox, Presto: Opera, Trident: MSIE, WebKit (forks): Chrome/Safari.

```
<form onabort="alert('the onabort event worked on this form?');">
```

There is an onsubmit event though, so you could try to combine that as the START point and then record if the user presses the escape key...

```
if (window.addEventListener) {document.addEventListener('keydown',keyPressed,false);}
else {document.attachEvent('onkeydown',keyPressed);}

function keyPressed(evt)
{
 var e = evt || event;
 var key = e.which || e.keyCode;

 switch (key)
 {
  // Esc
  case 27:
  alert('escape key pressed');
  break;

  case 76://L
  alert('L key pressed');
  break;
 }
}
```